# Only one onClick listener responds on initial startup android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I have 3 buttons and I'm working in mapsactivity. Only the first button responds, then the second, chronologically. I've stored markers in these buttons so I want them to respond independently when I click on anyone of them

Here is my .java file

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements  OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMaps);
    final Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonMaps2);
    final Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonMaps3);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedinstancestate) {
        super.onCreate(savedinstancestate);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                mMap.clear();
                if (button1.isShown()) {

                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(, )).title("").snippet("My Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)));

                    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            mMap.clear();
                            if (button2.isShown()) {

                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng()).title("").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_hospital)));
                                                              mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(), ));

                                button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {

                                        mMap.clear();
                                        if (button3.isShown()) {

                                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(`enter code here`)).title(" ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_busstop)));
                                                              mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(), ));

                                        }

                                    }

                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng ( ),));
    }
}
```

Here is my activity_maps.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity">

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MapsActivity"
            tools:layout="@android:layout/simple_spinner_dropdown_item" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="text1"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:background="#53fed0"
            android:id="@+id/buttonMaps"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text2"
            android:id="@+id/buttonMaps2"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonMaps"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bus Stops"
            android:id="@+id/buttonMaps3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonMaps2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:clickable="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am wondering why any button responds. You initialize your buttons BEFORE `setContentView`, that should be done AFTER. And if you want every button to respond separated, just set every `setOnClickListener` outside the other `setOnClickListener`. What you have done is, that button 2 is set to click listener by clicking button 1. And button 3 is set to click listener by click on button 2.

Comment: whats the point of setting onClickListener inside another onClickListener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define the button 2-3 press only when you press the button 1. need to identify separately.

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mMap.clear();
            if (button1.isShown()) {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(, )).title("").snippet("My Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)));

            }
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mMap.clear();
            if (button2.isShown()) {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng()).title("").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_hospital)));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(), ));


            }
        }
    });

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mMap.clear();
            if (button3.isShown()) {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(`enter code here`)).title(" ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_busstop)));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(), ));
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I want my markersto open a fragment on top of the map when I click on them. This fragment will show some text . I want this fragment to overlay only a part of the googlemap and to be closeable.  I already have some basic info in the 'snippet' that opens one click, but i want a better view of the info I have. Please kindly help

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the onclicklisteners inside other onclicklisteners. in your implementation,when button1 is clicked, onclicklistener for button2 is set, and when button 2 is clicked(after button1 click), onclicklistnere for button3 is set. set all 3 onclicklisteners directly inside oncreate.